# Use the comparison test to determine if the series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}\limits^\infty \frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^2}$$

I tried to solve the question using  $\frac{1}{n^2}$  as my comparison but because $\frac{1}{n^2}$ would always be $\leq$ $\frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^2}$ . Its convergence doesn't say anything about the convergence of the series (by the direct comparison test).

Comment: $0<\dfrac{1}{n^2}\leq \dfrac{2+\cos(n)}{n^2}\leq \dfrac{3}{n^2}$.  What is more interesting is the upper bound of $\dfrac{3}{n^2}$ here, not the lower bound of $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz oh okay. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what JMoravitz said in the comments:

While $\frac{1}{n^2}\le\frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^2}$, you can instead compare it to $\frac{3}{n^2}$ which is always greater than or equal to $\frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^2}$. The convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{n^2}$ by the p-series test means $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^2}$ converges.